# Are there any statements similar to an "If Any" in Swift 3.0 Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, any

Is there any such statement to do something similar to below? or do I need to create a function?

```
let x=[Double](1.023, 2.023, 3.023, 4.023, 5.023)
ler y=[Double](3.001)

if any of x > y{
("YES")}
```

Comment: this is not Swift. post your actual code attempt. If y were just a Double (not an array) you could use contains(where:) `if x.contains(where: { $0 > y }) {
    print(true)
}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `contains(where:)` method of Array.

```
let x = [1.023, 2.023, 3.023, 4.023, 5.023]
let y = 3.001
if x.contains(where: { $0 > y }) {
    print("YES")
}
```

If you want to know the first value that was greater, you can do:

```
let x = [1.023, 2.023, 3.023, 4.023, 5.023]
let y = 3.001
if let firstLarger = x.first(where: { $0 > y }) {
    print("Found \(firstLarger)")
}
```

If you want to know all that are larger, you can use `filter`.

```
let x = [1.023, 2.023, 3.023, 4.023, 5.023]
let y = 3.001
let matches = x.filter { $0 > y }
print("The following are greater: \(matches)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = [1.023, 2.023, 3.023, 4.023, 5.023]
let y = [3.001]
let result = x.filter { $0 > y[0] }

print(result) // [3.023, 4.023, 5.023]
```